# How to make a relative timestamp using ms (Or any other way), Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to make a revive command, however, I'd like to have a count down on this command, I've tried a lot of ways, but it requires a Unix code, I tried to find a way to turn Milliseconds into Unix Code, but I didn't find anything, my goal is to make it reply with `Wasn't on cooldown!` when there is no cooldown running, and `Cooldown! (Relative Timestamp Going with the cooldown)` to make it easier to check if the cooldown is done, rather than having the spam the command on the last seconds. All I need is a way to convert Milliseconds into Unix Code, or any other way to use the databased cooldown to make a relative timestamp.

Code:

```js
/* DisShop Copyrights */

// Main Requirements \\

const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { Secrets, Channels, Guilds, Roles, Permission, Users } = require(`../../config`)


// Important Values \\

const commandInformation = 
{
    CommandName: "revive",
    Alias: [],
    ReqPermissions: [Permission.ADMIN],
    ReqRoles: [Roles.MAIN_DEVT, Roles.MAIN_TESTT],
    ReqUsers: []
}


// Optional Requirements \\

const { QuickDB } = require('quick.db');
const db = new QuickDB();

const ms = require('ms')
const { create } = require('discord-timestamps')

const anyRequiredRoles = commandInformation.ReqRoles.length > 0
const anyRequiredPermissions = commandInformation.ReqPermissions.length > 0
const anyRequiredUsers = commandInformation.ReqUsers.length > 0

const anyRequirements = anyRequiredRoles == false && anyRequiredPermissions == false && anyRequiredUsers == false

// Code \\

module.exports = client => {
    client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
        if (message.author.bot) return
        if (!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(Secrets.PREFIX.toLowerCase())) return

        const command = message.content.toLowerCase()
        const args = command.replace(Secrets.PREFIX.toLowerCase(), '').split(' ')

        if (args[0].toString().toLowerCase() == commandInformation.CommandName || commandInformation.Alias.includes(args[0])) {

            // Permit Check \\

            var Permited_2 = 0

            var Permited_1 = 0

            if (anyRequiredUsers) {
                if (commandInformation.ReqUsers.some(userid => message.author.id == userid)) Permited_1++;
            }

            if (anyRequiredPermissions || anyRequiredRoles) {
                if (anyRequiredPermissions && !Permited_1 >= 1) {
                    if (commandInformation.ReqPermissions.some(permission => message.member.permissions.has(permission))) Permited_2++;
                }
                if (anyRequiredRoles && Permited_2 <= 0 && !Permited_1 >= 1) {
                    if (commandInformation.ReqRoles.some(role => message.member.roles.cache.has(role))) Permited_2++;
                }
            }

            if (!Permited_1 >= 1 && !Permited_2 >= 1 && anyRequiredUsers) {
                const promises = commandInformation.ReqUsers.map(
                    async (user) => await message.guild.members.fetch(user),
                );
                const allowedUsersList = await Promise.all(promises);
                const tags = allowedUsersList.map((m) => m.user.tag);

                return message.reply(`You're not allowed to use this command, only \`${tags.join('`, `')}\` can.`)
            } else if (!Permited_1 >= 1 && !Permited_2 >= 1 && !anyRequiredUsers) {
                return message.reply(`Sorry, you don't have the required permissions and/or roles.`)
            }

            if (!Permited_1 >= 1 && !Permited_2 >= 1) return message.reply(`Sorry, you don't have the required permissions and/or roles.`)

            // Main Code \\

            let ReviveCooldown = 1.8e+6; // 30 Minutes in ms

            let cooldownDB = await db.get(`ReviveCooldown`);

            if (ReviveCooldown - (Date.now() - cooldownDB) > 0){
                let timeObj = ms(ReviveCooldown - (Date.now() - cooldownDB));
                console.log(timeObj, cooldownDB, Date.now(), ReviveCooldown - (Date.now() - cooldownDB)/1000)
                if (timeObj.includes('ms')) timeObj = `Less than a second!`
                message.reply(`Cooldown! (Timestamp?)`)
            }
            else { 
                await db.set(`ReviveCooldown`, Date.now());
                message.reply(`Wasn't on cooldown!`)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

More info:

```json
  "dependencies":
    "better-sqlite3": "^7.6.2",
    "discord.js": "^13.10.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.2",
    "ms": "^2.1.3",
    "quick.db": "^9.0.6"
    
    "node": "16.14.2"
```

Thank you! (There are no errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to define a function that took a timestamp parameter and we had to divide it by 1000 to convert ms to seconds.
Let's say you took a current timestamp + add 30mins to it and feed it to the function, it will return the discord Embeddable countdown timer for 30mins.

```js
const getCDStamp = (timestamp = Date.now()) => `<t:${Math.round(timestamp / 1000)}:R>`;
```

Full Code: https://sourceb.in/ki3jQuUXwe